# removeExpiredCookie() doesn't work

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I am trying to clean my `WebView` by doing this in the `onDestroy`: `CookieManager.getInstance().removeExpiredCookie();`

This is the cookie that I am trying to clean:

```
expires=Sun, 17-Jan-2012 19:14:07 GMT; req_country=Israel; req_country_code=IL; req_ip=84.108.190.134;
```

Why is it that it is not being removed after `removeExpiredCookie()`?

Answer (score 1):

`CookieManager#.removeExpiredCookie()` does the actual deletion on a separate thread. If you wait for a bit, or do a `CookieSyncManager.sync()` (which is also asynchronous), it might work.

Another [workaround](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16543) suggests calling `CookieManager.setCookie` on all the cookies you want to remove, but that's only useful if you know the cookies and urls beforehand.